# Binary Deserializing implementations of an abstract class

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an abstract class that I'm trying to serialize and deserialize the concrete implementations of. In my abstract base class I have this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyAbstractBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    // some other abstract methods that derived classes have to implement
}
```

And to that class I add a method to serialize:

```
public string SerializeBase64()
{
    // Serialize to a base 64 string
    byte[] bytes;
    long length = 0;
    MemoryStream ws = new MemoryStream();
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(this.GetType());
    XmlDictionaryWriter binaryDictionaryWriter = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(ws);
    serializer.WriteObject(binaryDictionaryWriter, this);
    binaryDictionaryWriter.Flush();
    length = ws.Length;
    bytes = ws.GetBuffer();
    string encodedData = bytes.Length + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
    return encodedData;
}
```

This seems to work fine, in that it produces "something" and doesn't actually throw any errors.

Of course, the problem comes with deserialization. I added this:

```
public static MyAbstractBase DeserializeBase64(string s)
{
    int p = s.IndexOf(':');
    int length = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(0, p));
    // Extract data from the base 64 string!
    byte[] memorydata = Convert.FromBase64String(s.Substring(p + 1));
    MemoryStream rs = new MemoryStream(memorydata, 0, length);
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyAbstractBase ), new List<Type>() { typeof(SomeOtherClass.MyDerivedClass) });
    XmlDictionaryReader binaryDictionaryReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(rs, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);   
    return (MyAbstractBase)serializer.ReadObject(binaryDictionaryReader);
}
```

I thought by adding the "known types" to my `DataContractSerializer`, it would be able to figure out how to deserialize the derived class, but it appears that it doesn't. It complains with the error:

> Expecting element 'MyAbstractBase' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.Foo'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'SomeOtherClass.MyDerivedClass', namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.Foo.Bar'.

So any idea what I'm missing here?

I put together a simple demonstration of the problem on a dot net fiddle here:

http://dotnetfiddle.net/W7GCOw

Unfortunately, it won't run directly there because it doesn't include the `System.Runtime.Serialization` assemblies. But if you drop it into a Visual Studio project, it will serialize fine, but balks at deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I identified a couple of problems. The first is that the `CreateBinaryWriter` just doesn't seem to work at all. So I dropped it and just directly serialized with `serializer.WriteObject(ws,this);`

The second problem is on serialization I did this:

```
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(this.GetType(), new List<Type>() { typeof(SomeOtherClass.MyDerivedClass) });
```

The problem is that the type I'm passing there isn't the base type, it's whatever type I'm calling this function from. But in deserialization I have this:

```
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyAbstractBase ), new List<Type>() { typeof(SomeOtherClass.MyDerivedClass) });
```

This isn't the same serializer. The type is different. So changing both to `typeof(MyAbstractBase)` fixed the problem in my simple example.

Of course, in my real project I'm still getting errors with it complaining on deserialization with `The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.` which is odd because I've compared both the data coming out of serialization and the data going into deserialization and they are absolutely identical. No rogue BOM or anything.

**EDIT**: I've solved the `data at the root level is invalid` problem. It seems that decorating my `[DataContract]` attributes with explicit `Name` and `Namespace` properties solved the problem and, as an added bonus, reduced the size of my data because I greatly shortened the namespaces. Quite why the serializer couldn't cope with the *real* namespaces I don't know.

**Another Edit**: One last wrinkle. I think the namespace thing was a red herring and I got it working *only* by pure coincidence. The root of the problem (along with the solution) is explained here:

https://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2009/04/29/datacontractserializer-readobject-is-easily-confused.aspx

When you do `GetBuffer()` on the `MemoryStream` you can get excess null characters because of the way the underlying array resizes itself as needed. This puts a bunch of nulls on the end of your serialization (which can be spotted as a bunch of `A`s after base 64'ing the array) and these are what are screwing up the deserialization with the *very* confusing `The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`. It's confusing because the problem *isn't* at the beginning at all, it's at the **END**!!!

In case anybody is interested, by serialization now looks like this:

```
    public string SerializeBase64()
    {
        // Serialize to a base 64 string
        byte[] bytes;
        long length = 0;
        using (MemoryStream ws = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(ws);
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyAbstractBase ), new List<Type>() { typeof(SomeOtherClass.MyDerivedClass) });
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, this);
            writer.Flush();
            length = ws.Length;
            // Note: https://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2009/04/29/datacontractserializer-readobject-is-easily-confused.aspx
            // We need to trim nulls from the buffer produced by the serializer because it'll barf on them when it tries to deserialize.
            bytes = new byte[ws.Length];
            Array.Copy(ws.GetBuffer(), bytes, bytes.Length);
        }
        string encodedData = bytes.Length + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
        return encodedData;
    }
```

Comment: In the above code, shouldn't you be using `ws.ToArray()` instead of `ws.GetBuffer()` and `Array.Copy()`?  See [When is GetBuffer() on MemoryStream ever useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13053739/10263).  I think that would both eliminate the problem and simplify your code at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

When serializing your data, use the same overloaded method for serialization as you use for deserialization:

```
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyAbstractBase ), new List<Type>() { typeof(SomeOtherClass.MyDerivedClass) });
```

Also, Declare a KnownType attribute around your base class so it knows what possible derived classes it may deserialize:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(SomeOtherclass.MyDerivedClass))]
public class MyAbstractBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    // some other abstract methods that derived classes have to implement
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Elsewhere in my project I was setting up default serializers to cover derived classes, so that's why I didn't need it for serialization (and shouldn't need it for deserialization either, but I wasn't sure it was actually picking it up). And the `KnownType` attribute is just an alternative to providing a list of types to the serializer anyway. I'm pretty sure you only need one or the other (but I did try both just to be sure and I have the same problem).