# When will MemoryStream.TryGetBuffer return a useful ArraySegment?

Tags: .net, memorystream

[`bool MemoryStream.TryGetBuffer(out ArraySegment<byte> buffer)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.trygetbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx) is a new API in .NET 4.6 that can be used to get access to the valid bytes stored in the MemoryStream without copying them. This is very exciting! It returns a bool that is "true if the conversion was successful; otherwise, false" and populates the out param.

When does it return true, indicating that the `out ArraySegment<byte> buffer` now contains valid information? This isn't documented today.

I know that if it returns false, I can use [`.ToArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a copy of the bytes. And, we've have [`.GetBuffer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx), but sometimes MemoryStreams are created with an offset into the buffer, and this information is [hard (well, sort of) to get later on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30089373/2392683), not to mention the `try ... catch` needed for robustness.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For `TryGetBuffer` to perform a successful conversion and populate the out param with useful information, the buffer must be visible. The buffer is visible if any of these constructors are used:

- `MemoryStream()`
- `MemoryStream(int capacity)`
- `MemoryStream(byte[] buffer, int index, int count, bool writable, bool publiclyVisible)` with `publiclyVisible: true`.

Check the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/mscorlib/src/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs#L207) for more details.

Answer (score -4):

GetBuffer return all bytes in memory, independent of use,

ex:
Capacity = 100000, Length = 200

GetBuffer (and TryGetBuffer !?) return bytes( Capacity )

ToArray return bytes( Length )