# When using a memory stream to save, the C1XLWorkbook creates a file, but the file comes out corrupt. Why is that happening?

Tags: c#, excel, server, response, corrupt

I'm working with a C1XLBook object that I want to save to a memory stream so I can download it.  The code is as follows (memory stream and workbook were declared higher up):

```
            workbook.Save(ms);
            byte[] content = ms.GetBuffer();

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            string contentDisposition = "inline";
            string filename = "Worksbook.xls";

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition + "; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", content.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(content);
            Response.End();
```

The result is that a file gets downloaded by the client, but it ends up looking like this:
[image: Resulting Excel File]

However, when I save the file to my local system it comes out looking how I would expect.  Are there any thoughts for how this can be fixed?  I've been doing all kinds of research but I haven't found the answer yet.

I expected the data I had to get exported into the excel file in human readable form.  I've tried messing with the Response properties, I've tried changing the properties on the memory stream, I've messed with the encoding, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: After writing to ms you have to set the position to zero before reading the ms. (ms.Position = 0).  If you don't you should get nothing.  An Excel workbook is binary so results should look like what you posted.

Comment: I tried that but I still am observing the same result

Comment: @jdweng OP uses `.GetBuffer()` so they don't need to change position... Obviously in real code they would use correct length (Coliwack - make sure code shown actually reflects your real code - as one that is shown is clearly simplified version not taking into account lingth of the stream).

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Wait that is my real code...How am I supposed to account for the stream's length?

Comment: Unless you really must squeeze every once of performance use `ToArray`... Otherwise RTFM very carefully and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053739/when-is-getbuffer-on-memorystream-ever-useful

Comment: I also know that nothing is apparently wrong with the bytes, because when I do a File.writeallbytes with the byte array I have here, the file saves properly.

Comment: `Response.BinaryWrite(content, 0, ms.Length);` although it seems that isn't actually supported by System.Web. Also looks like the correct MIME type is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2007-resource-kit/ee309278(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN And why have you set it to `inline`?

Comment: ToArray() didn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Charlieface BinaryWrite doesn't take three arguments, it would appear.

Comment: Oh oops I forgot to read the rest of the comment.  Since I want a local download I probably shouldn't have it be inline, I should have it be attachment.

Comment: Presumably you're using WebForms, so you should use an [ashx handler](https://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx), not an aspx page. Also, Response.End can break it in some versions of some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this worked, but the way I solved it was simply to remove `Response.ClearHeaders()` and it started working.  If anyone knows why it worked I'd love to know... Seems weird that it'd be that simple.