# Avoiding MemoryStream.ToArray() when using System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive

Tags: c#

A helper method to turn a string into a zipped up text file:

```
public static System.Net.Mail.Attachment CreateZipAttachmentFromString(string content, string filename)
{
  using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
      ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(filename);
      using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(zipArchiveEntry.Open()))
      {
        streamWriter.Write(content);
      }

    }

    MemoryStream memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray(), false);

    return new Attachment(memoryStream2, filename + ".zip", MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);
  }
}
```

I was really hoping to avoid turning the first memory stream into an array, making another memory stream on it to read it, and passing that to attachment. My logic was, why copy X megabytes to another place in memory to establish another stream pointing to the copy, when it's essentially just what we started out with.. It's the multi-megabyte equivalent of redundancy like `if(myBool == true)`

So I figured instead I would Seek back to the start of the first memory stream, and then attachment could just read that.. Or I would establish another memorystream pointing to the buffer of the first, and with the offset and length parameters set so it would know what to read

Neither of these approaches work out because it seems that ZipArchive only pushes data into the memory stream (in my case maybe) when control falls out of the using block and the ziparchive is disposed. Disposing it also disposes the MemoryStream and nearly everything (other than ToArray() and GetBuffer()) throw ObjectDisposedException.

Ultimately I can't seek it or get its length after the ZipArchive pumps data into it and before it pumps it in, the offset is usually zero and the length is definitely zero so the values are useless

Is there a nice optimal way, short of configuring my own over-large buffer (which then makes it non expandable by MemoryStream), to avoid having to burn up around 2x the memory bytes of the archive size with this method?

Comment: A bit of prior knowledge here goes a long way... the implementation of `MemoryStream.Dispose` is there only to satisfy the interface it inherits from `Stream`. It does nothing (other than preventing further operations). i.e. you don't need to dispose of your MemoryStream instances.

Comment: @spender. actually, the `Dispose` method on the `MemoryStream` changes some flags in the object that will make the stream not readable and not writable.

Comment: @spender "`Dispose` does nothing" is a stretch - it marks stream "disposed" and blocks all Read/Write operations.

Comment: I just updated my comment @YacoubMassad after a peek with the decompiler.

Comment: Side note: Proper way to handle "multi-megabyte" streams in memory is to build/find chunked stream implementation as `MemoryStream` uses copy-on-grow approach that is very slow for large streams (make sure to measure for your case - may not be a problem, you can pre-grow to avoid copy when measuring time).

Comment: Alternatively write them not to a memory stream but a memory mapped file, a temporary file - something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Most well designed streams and stream-users in .NET have an additional boolean parameter that can be used to instruct them to leave the "base stream" (terrible name) open when disposing.

This is `ZipArchive`'s [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137431(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public ZipArchive(
    Stream stream,
    ZipArchiveMode mode,
    bool leaveOpen
)
```

Comment: And don't dispose the MemoryStream with `using`.

Comment: That's terrible advice, his problem was that the memory stream was being disposed while still inside the `using` block.

Comment: If he disposes it explicitly he will have the same problem as before. He can't dispose the stream if he wants to use it.

Comment: Where do you see explicit disposing of the memory stream while still inside the `using` block? Actually don't reply, print out his code, grab a pen and match those braces until you understand what's going on here.

Comment: Indeed, I mentally mismatched the braces. I wonder why. Maybe because of the two space tabs.

Comment: Indeed `bool leaveOpen` is the main piece of the puzzle. To make code look more correct you can still dispose `MemoryStream` as in OP's sample  but use `GetBuffer`+`Length` to avoid copy. Feel free to copy that code from my deleted post if you find that suggestion useful.

Comment: I don't, I see nothing wrong with just seeking in a memory stream.

Comment: @Blindy sure - strictly personal preference... Note so that if multiple people work on the code someone later may spend thay time on adding `using` to dispose memory stream and sitting puzzled why everything stop working :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if you create a fresh stream that one needs disposal by the same logic. (And in fact neither may be disposed at all. This is a flaw in this answer. The stream must survive the method exiting.)

Comment: The memory stream is already in an `using` block, and properly so. I still see nothing wrong.

Comment: @usr yes. Refactoring out method like "CreateStreamForAttachment" may  clarify that ownership of returned stream is expected to be passed to some other object.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a second `MemoryStream`. You need to do two things:

1. Ensure, that the `MemoryStream` is not disposed before the last usage point. This is harmless. Disposing a `MemoryStream` does nothing helpful and for compatibility reasons can never do anything in the future. The .NET Framework has a *very* high compatibility bar. They often don't even dare to rename fields.
2. Seek to offset zero.

So remove the `using` around the `MemoryStream` and use the ctor for `ZipArchive` that allows you to leave the stream open.

Since the `Attachment` you are returning makes use of the `MemoryStream` you can't dispose it before exiting the method. Again, this is harmless. The only negative point is that the code becomes less obvious.

There's an entirely different approach: You can write your own `Stream` class that creates the bytes on demand. That way there is no need to buffer the string and ZIP bytes at all. This is much more work, of course. And it does not detract from the fact that the whole string must sit in memory at once, so it's still not a O(1) space solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static System.Net.Mail.Attachment CreateZipAttachmentFromString(string content, string filename)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, true))
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(filename);
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(zipArchiveEntry.Open()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(content);
            }

        }

        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        return new Attachment(memoryStream, filename + ".zip", MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);
    }
```

Comment: Did you test whether the using needs to be removed? I answered that as well but honestly it's a guess.

Comment: yep, it needed to be removed like you had guessed. the stream appears to not actually be read from until client.Send() is called, so the using inside the method was getting in the way.